# Referencing Client Script Files in Kentico 12 MVC

Tags: kentico, kentico-mvc

We are new to *Kentico* having recently purchased a ***Kentico 12*** licence.

This is what we are trying to do:

1. Create a new **CSS Stylesheet** and **JavaScript File** in the
   *Development* section of the *CMS*
2. On a single, custom *MVC* page, reference these client resources
   using standard HTML references, something like:

```
<link href="{Reference-to-CSS}"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css" />

<script src="{Reference-to-JavaScript}" type="text/javascript" />
```

I have looked at the Kentico 12 API documentation and I think I need to use the `CssLinkHelper.GetStylesheetUrl()` helper method for the CSS, but I can't find an equivalent for the JavaScript.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you are managing them in the CMS site instead of the MVC site?

Comment: Only because site admins want to ‘adjust’ these two scripts from time to time

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [ScriptHelper](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/understanding-the-scripthelper-api-in-kentico). Here are [all the methods](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/12_0/api/html/Methods_T_CMS_Base_Web_UI_ScriptHelper.htm).